# How to animate the opacity of a texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

I painted a red circular spot using texture painting over a UV Sphere with an image texture. Is it possible to animate the opacity of the red spot?

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a way to mix the basic material and your spot image texture, for example use a *MixRGB* and plug the *Alpha* of the *Image Texture* in the factor socket, then find a way to vary the alpha value, here with a *Converter > Math (Multiply)*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found an addon named Texture Paint Layers in which there is an option to change and animate the opacity of each layer.

Comment: oh ok, anyway I think it just automatically generates some nodes setups, it's always good to know how they work

Comment: Thank for your answer and yeah absolutely ! Its great to know the mechanism